# ActiveRecord belongs_to association id is not always set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have models like this:

```
class Member
  belongs_to :team, class_name: 'Team'
end

class Team
  has_many :members, foreign_key: :team_id
end
```

Database has all the columns needed.

When I do:
    t = Team.new
    m = Member.new

```
m.team = team
m.save!
#some other code
t.save!
```

team_id field is present most of the times but is absent sometimes in the database. I saw in active record documentation that belongs to association is not saved. This looks like a race condition to me but I want to understand why it might happen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `t = Team.create; t.members.new` will create through the association and assign the fields automatically.

Comment: @anothermh any idea why above works sometimes but not always?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always create associated objects through the association. That means that you should do the following:

```
t = Team.create!
m = t.members.create!
```

This is described in greater detail in the guide for [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark).

You asked why the example you provided works sometimes but not others. I cannot replicate the problems that you're seeing. It is probably something specific to your implementation or practices that are not shared in your question. Here is how I verified that the issue does not occur.

First, create the Rails app, its associations, its database, and then start the Rails console:

```
rails new tester
cd tester
rails generate model Team
rails generate model Member team:belongs_to
sed -i '' 's/end/  has_many :members\'$'\nend/' app/models/team.rb
rake db:migrate
rails console
```

Now create one thousand teams with an associated member, and if the fields are not appropriately set then raise an exception:

```
1000.times do
  t = Team.create!
  m = t.members.create!
  raise unless m.team_id && m.team_id == t.id
end
```

Or alternatively, using `.new` and `.save!`:

```
1000.times do
  t = Team.new
  m = t.members.new
  m.save!
  raise unless m.team_id && m.team_id == t.id
end
```

No exception is raised, so by creating in this manner you can be assured that it will work properly.